# Tomcat 7 + IntelliJ The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core Issue

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7

I'm having really big problem with running webapp on tomcat 7 from IntelliJ (Ultimate) IDE. The problem is, that I can't get working `taglib`s for my jsp. Doesn't really matter what kind of taglib I'm trying to add, it's not working anyway. The JSP only have taglibs:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="dec" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
```

And the exception (for EVERY taglib):

```
23:50:22,420 ERROR UnhandledExceptionsFilter:34 - Unhandled exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at pl.com.suadeo.utils.UnhandledExceptionsFilter.doFilter(UnhandledExceptionsFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Or:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at pl.com.suadeo.utils.UnhandledExceptionsFilter.doFilter(UnhandledExceptionsFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And it goes for every taglib I declared. My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>powiazania</artifactId>
    <name>Powiązania</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.1.4.Final</hibernate-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.16</log4j-version>
        <commons-collections-version>3.2</commons-collections-version>
        <jackson-jaxrs-version>1.9.8</jackson-jaxrs-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Related to Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Display tag do paginacji -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsony do ajaxowych requestow przez jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-jaxrs-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- do zarzadzania annotacjami "scope" -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SiteMesh -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--  JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <relativePath>/</relativePath>
                    <war>`
                        <path>
                            D:/java-stuff/intellij-workspace/powiazania/target
                        </path>
                    </war>
                    <alwaysGenerate>true</alwaysGenerate>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <!--<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>-->
                    <!--<showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Yet it's not working anyway. What's most interesting, is that when I copy the exact war generated into `../webapps` directory in Tomcat, and run manually, it works. Any clue why it's not working from IDE?

Comment: Isn't it complaining about a sitemesh taglib, and I don't see a trace of sitemesh in your dependencies

Comment: It's complaining about every taglib, not only sitemesh, thats the issue. Anyway, I commented out everything except jstl, and it leaves me with exact exception

Comment: I don't see the JSTL taglibs in your dependencies either. You don't have any taglib in your dependencies, so every taglib that you'll try to use will cause this exception.

Comment: @JBNizet Sitemesh'es taglibs are included via dependency (included my whole pom.xml), yet still exception is thrown. I've tried both Tomcat 6 with servlet 2.5 and Tomcat 7 with servlet 3.0. The result is still the same, can't run my web app via IDE

Answer (score 5):

I used your POM to create a hello world webapp with the JSTL taglib being used on my hello.jsp page. Works fine. I can reproduce your issue by removing the jstl dependency in my POM and doing a clean build and deploy. So it seems as if the tag lib jars are in the classpath when you are running the webapp via IDEA. Since they are in your POM with a compile, they should be. Or more specifically, they should be in the artifact. Since you mention that you can copy the war to Tomcat and run it successfully, that leads me to believe that when are running your webapp via IDEA it is not using that artifact (i,e, the war file) for deployment. It is not uncommon when creating a tomcat run/debug configuration in IDEA to have it deploy the exploded war rather than the war file itself. That gives the advantage of being able to update resources on the fly.

Here are some things you can check:

Go into your tomcat run/debug configuration. On the *Deployment* tab, look at what artifact is being deployed. It should be either `maven-module-name:war` or `maven-module-name:war exploded`. If not, change it one of those. If it is, select it and click the edit icon. This will open the artifact definition in the *Project Structure* dialog. If it was the war file, it should show the archive definition as being a war of the exploded directory. Select (in the middle pane) the `maven-module-name:war exploded` artifact. Expand the WEB-INF/lib directory. Make sure the tag lib jars show in there. If not, you can try re-importing the maven project from the maven tool window to get things synchronized. You may have to run it 2 or 3 times. (I've experienced a case sometime where that is necessary). Once the artifact is corrected, you should be good to go.

If the artifact is fine, try doing a full manual clean of everything. It's possible IDEA thinks the jars are present when they are not. When you start tomcat, in the console output, you should see `CATALINA_BASE` set to a directory in IDEA's config directory. After toping IDEA, go and delete that directory. Then delete the `${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps` directory (or at the very least your applications directory and any war files). Next delete the target (or out) directory to which IDEA is building. After that try starting up the tomcat instance through IDEA.

If the webapp cleaning does not work, try invalidating the caches *File > Invalidate Caches*, restarting IDEA, and letting it re-index the project. You may want to couple this one with a full clean of the webapp again.

If none of those things work, my best recommendation is to try creating fresh IDEA project by importing your pom file (*File > Import Project* and select the pom).

Oh, and just in case, make sure you are using the latest version of IDEA, 12.1.6 (or the latest your license is valid for). Sometimes its the simple things ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must add javax.servlet.jstl library into the artifact of the project so that it will add the jstl library into the .war file. Hope this will help.

[See attached picture for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jnly.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on web.xml in intellij (Eclipse):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    
</web-app>
```